# Get PHP or Javascript response from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, discord, discord.js

I have a node.js program specifically a discord bot using discord.js. I am trying to integrate Googles Teachable Machine API which is just a super easy way of training an image classifier and getting fast results. 
The problem I am facing is that the API supports javascript but not node.js so I can get results from an html or php file by passing an image link in the header of the url, but I don't know how I can get a result back to my node.js application. I was thinking about creating a php script to echo the data, but I get the data from javascript in the first place and the node.js request functions don't wait for my php script to finish executing before giving a response. So is there a way to wait for a response from a php script? The image classifier takes a few seconds to get a result.

Upon further attempts, I tried to get the script to write to a file and get node.js to just read from the file a few seconds after, but calling the php script via

```
request.get('php file url', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

    }
});
```

doesnt seem to make the php script do any writing to any files even though when I run it in my browser it does. So does a request to a php file not make it execute the php code?

Shortened version:
I have a node.js application which needs data from a php file but the php file uses javascript to generate the data. How can I get the data from the php script?

Edit: Add php code
This is basically all my php code. Most of it is javascript which I need to get the data.

```
$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET["URL"]);
if(empty($url)) {
    $error = "No URL Provided.";
}
$myfile = fopen("../test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $url);
fclose($myfile);
```

Then I use  in my javascript code to get the image url.

Comment: Can you share your PHP code as well?

Comment: Edited with php code

Answer (score 0):

I demoted the previous answer. While it was 3 years ago, **no question is ridiculous**! For anyone searching for more information on PHP with node.js, check out these two options on npm:

PHP: https://www.npmjs.com/package/php?activeTab=code

PHP-SERVER: https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-server

You can also use JAVASCRIPT or AJAX to call a php file on your server, just make sure that you are using json_encode() to output your response. Here is a great tutorial of 5 different ways to call php:
https://code-boxx.com/call-php-file-from-javascript/

I hope this helps, and remember no question is stupid, this entire site exists based on questions. Happy day!

Answer (score -1):

Using PHP is absurd and you seem to confuse client-side with server-side JavaScript.

The models created with [Teachable Machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) are TensorFlow models -
and therefore can be used in a NodeJS environment with [TensorFlow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js).

Comment: I understand that but Teachable Machine requires either a HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, or an ImageBitmap. This cant be done in node can it as it doesnt have any HTML elements? All I have to work with is an image url.

Comment: You'll have to fetch the image first. There is no API at all (opposite to Cloud Vision or Cloud ML), but it runs locally.  Teachable Machine generally is a web-based generator for ML models, which you can use to train the models - but the detection is done with TensorFlow (which assumes, the machine had already been taught).

Comment: How can I fetch the remote image? Do you mean I have to download the image locally from the image url? Is that using the node-fetch module?

Comment: It depends if you want to use it for training (using the web-based editor) or for detection (using TensorFlow.js). In the first place, you'd need to train a model or use an existing one.

Comment: I already have a model trained. I only want to use the detection from an image url.